# If anyone could explain to me what is going on here

Tags: c++, function, stack, operators, bit-manipulation

Somewhere in my program i have a function

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) if (!(mask & 1 << i))

{

   string tmp = s;

   b[i](tmp);

   mask |= 1 << i;

   generate(tmp, mask, count - 1);
}
```

However if i change a single thing (which presumably) should be the same, the code doesn't as it should anymore.

If instead of

```
mask |= 1 << i;

generate(tmp, mask, count - 1);
```

i write  `generate(tmp, mask | (1 << i), count - 1)`

Comment: What's the return type of generate?

Comment: Please edit the subject of your question and make it something more meaningful that can be used in a search by future readers. "Can anyone explain to me what is going on here?" is pretty much meaningless. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's not the same thing.

```
mask |= 1 << i;
```

alters the variable `mask`, whereas your version - `mask | (1 << i)` - doesn't.

It's like saying `x += 1` and `x+1` don't behave the same - sure, the expression evaluates to the same thing, but `x` changes only for the first version.

Comment: No mask is not used anywhere else and return type of generate is void.

Comment: @user1871411 it makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

```
mask |= 1 << i;
```

can also be written as:

```
mask = mask | (1 << i);
```

In the original code, values of mask are: `1, 3, 7, 15`. However, your modified version generates: `1, 2, 4, 8`. So you can change it like this:

```
generate(tmp, mask = mask | (1 << i), count - 1)
```

to have the same values

Answer (score 1):

Mask is mutated on each iteration with the first statement. With the second there is no mutation. As a result the semantics are different, because mask has the same value on each iteration.